# C++ how to make available (without copying) parts of the static array as array-like objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, sub-array

I'm writing a high-performance communication library based on [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:cpp), where a single data packet consists of many smaller chunks, consumed by different routines. I want to avoid data copying. The received packet will be stored in the message structure available via shared pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<zmq::message_t> response = std::make_shared<zmq::message_t>();
socket.recv (req.get());
```

The data in the message may be accessed by a standard pointer:

```
uint32_t * msg_data = (uint 32_t *) response.get()->data();
```

However, I need to access them in another way.
Each consumer should be given its `result` object, that contains the shared pointer to the `response` array, and something that presents the appropriate part of the `data` field of the message as array-like object.
The `response` array will be disposed off as soon as the last consumer stops using its `result`.

If we assume that the data consists of 100 words, with 3 chunks starting at 0th, 23th and 65th word, the result should be prepared as follows:

```
shared_ptr<my_sub_array> res1 = std::make_shared<my_sub_array>(response,0,23);
shared_ptr<my_sub_array> res2 = std::make_shared<my_sub_array>(response,23,65);
shared_ptr<my_sub_array> res1 = std::make_shared<my_sub_array>(response,65,100);
```

It seems, that `my_sub_array` may be based on [`span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) class (with addition of the shared pointer to `response` ensuring that it is not released). However it has been introduced in C++20, so is not supported yet by most compilers.

Is there any official and portable way to produce such array-like representation of the part of an array?

**Update**

For performance reasons listed in comments below, the `result` objects should be returned via `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`:

```
unique_ptr<my_sub_array> res1 = std::make_unique<my_sub_array>(response,0,23);
unique_ptr<my_sub_array> res2 = std::make_unique<my_sub_array>(response,23,65);
unique_ptr<my_sub_array> res1 = std::make_unique<my_sub_array>(response,65,100);
```

Comment: You want to avoid copying?  Because of the perceived cost?  Have you measured that vs. the atomic operations required for keeping the shared pointer alive?

Comment: Maybe [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md) would be helpful here? (implementation here https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span ). Otherwise why not just a *beginning* and *end* pointer to deliniate the region?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a span-like class to do this.   or just pass pointers.  It being "official" doesn't make it any better.  Also, shared_ptr's are relatively expensive to create/destroy so that design decision seems questionable for something that will have a lot of creation/deletion.

Comment: Thanks for comments regarding the shared pointers. Indeed I may use unique_ptr for passing the "result". However of course a shared_ptr to the "response" will be needed in "my_sub_array" to keep the "response" alive.
For "span" I have found the following portable implementation: https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite